# Order of floated elements is reversed

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to achieve this layout:

```
********* 
* Image *  Price | Add-to-cart-icon | Amount
*********
```

But as you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rn7wrynp/1/), the order of "Price | Add-to-cart-icon | Amount" is "Add-to-cart-icon | Amount | Price". Why is this happening and how can I achieve the pursued layout?
Maybe it is better to align elements by using `display: inline`?

My HTML-Code:

```
 <div class="views-column">
  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Vitoria_-_Museo_Ciencias_Naturales16.JPG">
  <div class="feldgruppe">
    10,00 €
    <form class="commerce-add-to-cart">
      <div>
        <input src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/shopping_cart_icon_vector_red_background_280670.jpg" class="form-submit" type="image">
        <div class="form-item-quantity">
          <label>Anzahl </label>
          <input size="3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-column">
  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Pyrite_from_Ampliaci%C3%B3n_a_Victoria_Mine%2C_Navaj%C3%BAn%2C_La_Rioja%2C_Spain_2.jpg">
  <div class="feldgruppe">
    19,00 €
    <form class="commerce-add-to-cart">
      <div>
        <input name="submit" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/shopping_cart_icon_vector_red_background_280670.jpg" class="form-submit" type="image">
        <div class="form-item-quantity">
          <label>Anzahl </label>
          <input size="3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
    .views-column {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.views-column img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 35%;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.feldgruppe,
.commerce-add-to-cart {
  float: left;
}

input.form-submit {
  float: left;
  max-width: 30px;
}

.form-item-quantity {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/teutak/rn7wrynp/4/

Comment: Yes, thank you. I totally oversaw that the price wasn't floated at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use float for all, you should wrap the *price* text into a `div` or `span` and float it to the left too. But I suggest to use inline blocks instead of float, so less CSS is needed.

```
.views-column img {
  max-width: 35%;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.views-column div,
.views-column form {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input.form-submit {
  max-width: 30px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcgtnLck/)**

```css
.views-column {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 1em;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
}

.views-column img {
  max-width: 35%;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.views-column div,
.views-column form {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input.form-submit {
  max-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="views-column">
  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Vitoria_-_Museo_Ciencias_Naturales16.JPG">
  <div class="feldgruppe">
    10,00 €
    <form class="commerce-add-to-cart">
      <div>
        <input src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/shopping_cart_icon_vector_red_background_280670.jpg" class="form-submit" type="image">
        <div class="form-item-quantity">
          <label>Anzahl </label>
          <input size="3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-column">
  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Pyrite_from_Ampliaci%C3%B3n_a_Victoria_Mine%2C_Navaj%C3%BAn%2C_La_Rioja%2C_Spain_2.jpg">
  <div class="feldgruppe">
    19,00 €
    <form class="commerce-add-to-cart">
      <div>
        <input name="submit" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/shopping_cart_icon_vector_red_background_280670.jpg" class="form-submit" type="image">
        <div class="form-item-quantity">
          <label>Anzahl </label>
          <input size="3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```